# expand an array of arrays to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays and I need to make the first member in each nested array into a key, and make an array of objects from the rest. Where each odd member after the first is key and an even member is value.

See the example: note that the original nested arrays always have an odd number or members (or even after you remove the first member to make it our new key)

```
//ORIGINAL
    var arr = [
     [first, a, b, c, d],[second, e, f, g, h, i, j],[third,...]
    ]

// DESIRED RESULT
    var obj = [
     {first: [{a:b}, {c:d}]},
     {second: [{e:f}, {g:h}, {i:j}]},
     {third: ...}
    ]
```

Comment: [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will be your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array.map` and ES6 destructuring & rest operators and dynamic object keys:

```js
var arr = [
  ["first", "a", "b", "c", "d"],["second", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],["third"]
]

var obj = arr.map(([key, ...rest]) => {
  let res = { [key]: [] }
  for(let i = 0; i < rest.length; i+=2)
    res[key].push({ [rest[i]]: rest[i+1] });
  return res;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the sub-arrays with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of objects. Use destructuring to take the 1st item of each sub array (the key), and rest to get the other items (the values). Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the values (all items but the 1st) to an array of objects.

```js
const arr = [
  ['first', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['second', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
]

const result = arr.map(([key, ...values]) => ({ // map the sub-arrays to objects
  [key]: Array.from({ length: values.length / 2 }, (_, i) => ({ // generate an array of objects from the values
    [values[i * 2]]: values[i * 2 + 1]
  }))
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This was my output too but it doesn't actually match OPs requirements which is an array of objects.

Comment: @Nick - thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to:

```js
var arr = [
  ['first', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['second', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
]

function format(array) {
  return array.map(array => {
    const firstItem = array[0]
    const resultArray = []
    for (let i = 2; i < array.length; i += 2) {
      resultArray.push({ [array[i - 1]]: array[i] })
    }
    return { [firstItem]: resultArray }
  })
}

console.log(format(arr));
```